# The file size (mb) is larger when building aab than building with apk in android

Tags: android, react-native, flutter, kotlin, google-play

i'm using react-native with Android
when i build my app
The file size (mb) is larger when building aab than building with apk.

However, building with aab should be smaller.

i saw the app capacity in the app information in the Google Play Store internal test.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that AAB is larger than a single APK because an App Bundle is a bundle of APK. If you compile to APK you normally create at least 4 APKs or one universal APK.